# Program runs in pycharm but will not run in the console

Tags: python

This is my first programming language class, so please be patient. The program runs fine in pycharm. But when I try to run the program in C:\WINDOWS\py.exe it will populate the first question of my program. when I answer the question it closes suddenly.

```
pounds = float(input('Please enter the value of pounds you wish to convert to kilograms: '))
kilograms = pounds * 0.45359237
print("The conversion to kilograms is: ", format(kilograms, '.2f'))
```

Comment: that's logical: after it the `print`, it ends, so it closes the console window.

Comment: What would I need to change in order to keep it open?

Comment: add `end = input('Press enter to quit')` at the end of your script

Comment: Newby mistake. I put input() at the end of code and it is now working fine.